# chatmulticast em java

Tags: java

Tenho um pequeno problema neste código abaixo em java.

É um chat multicast

Erro principal está no construtor comentado.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author tanira
 */
public class EmissorReceptor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<String> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int porta;
    private final String ip;
    InetAddress group;
    MulticastSocket s;


    //da erro nesse construtor, a causa eh os argumentos que se pede
    public EmissorReceptor(String ip, int Porta) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.porta = Porta;
    }
    private EmissorReceptor() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void Conecta(String ip, int porta) {
        try {
            //define o IP do grupo
            group = InetAddress.getByName(this.ip);
            //cria um socket com a porta expecificada
            s = new MulticastSocket(this.porta);
            //entra no grupo multicast
            s.joinGroup(group);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problemas ao conectar.");
        }
    }

    public void atualizaMsg(String msg) {
        this.jTAChat.append(msg + "\n");
    }

    public void limpaListaClientes() {
        this.jTAClientes.setText("");
    }

    public void atualizaClientes(String cliente) {
        if (!listaClientes.contains(cliente)) {
            listaClientes.add(cliente);//adicionar um novo cliente caso o nome dele nao esteja na lista dos clientes
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++) {
            this.jTAClientes.append(listaClientes.get(i) + "\n");
        }

    }

    public void enviaMsg(String msg) {
        try {
            Conecta(this.ip, this.porta);
            //CRIA UM PACOTE DATAGRAMA
            DatagramPacket mensagem = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), group, porta);
            //ENVIA A MENSAGEM AO GRUPO MULTICAST
            s.send(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problemas ao enviar mensagem.");
        }
    }

    public void recebeMsg(String msg) {
        Conecta(this.ip, this.porta);// se conecta ao grupo multicast para pode receber as mensagens
        new Thread() {//utiliza thread pra nao bloquear
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    byte[] bufferRec = new byte[100];
                    DatagramPacket pacoteRec = new DatagramPacket(bufferRec, bufferRec.length);
                    try {
                        s.receive(pacoteRec);
                        bufferRec = pacoteRec.getData();
                        String msgRec = new String(bufferRec, 0, pacoteRec.getLength());
                        String msgRecebida= new String(bufferRec, 0, pacoteRec.getLength());

                        //trata a msg
                        msgRec = msgRec.toLowerCase(); //deixa tudo em minusculo                        
                        String ajustes = msgRec.replace("disse:", "");// retira o disse: para poder manusear o nick e a msg em si
                        String partes[] = ajustes.split(" ");//deve ficar partes[0]= NICK || partes[1]= msg

                        if (!listaClientes.contains(partes[0])) {
                            listaClientes.add(partes[1]);//adicionar um novo cliente caso AINDA o nome dele nao esteja na lista dos clientes
                            atualizaClientes(partes[1]);

                        } else if (partes[0].equals("sair")) {//caso o cliente queira sair retira o nome dlee da lista e mostra a nova no chat
                            listaClientes.remove(listaClientes.indexOf(partes[0]));
                            atualizaClientes(listaClientes);
                        }
                        //agora passa a msgRec pra tela no atualiza msg (chama o metodo)
                        atualizaMsg(msgRecebida);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(EmissorReceptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        System.out.println("Problemas na thread receptora.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTAChat = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTFIp = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTFNick = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jBConectar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTFMensagem = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jBEnviar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTAClientes = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTAChat.setColumns(20);
        jTAChat.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTAChat);

        jLabel1.setText("IP Multicast:");

        jTFIp.setText("localhost");

        jLabel2.setText("Nick:");

        jBConectar.setText("Conectar");
        jBConectar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBConectarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Clientes:");

        jBEnviar.setText("Enviar");
        jBEnviar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBEnviarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTAClientes.setColumns(20);
        jTAClientes.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTAClientes);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jTFMensagem)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jBEnviar))
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 611, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 188, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jTFIp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addComponent(jTFNick, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                        .addComponent(jBConectar)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jTFIp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jTFNick, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jBConectar)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 380, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTFMensagem, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jBEnviar))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jBConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBConectarActionPerformed
        //o metodo conecta serve nesse caso principalmente pra salvar o IP do cliente ja que no envia msg ele chamara o
        //conecta novamente
        Conecta(this.jTFIp.getText(), 3456);//Nesse caso dar uma porta estatica
        //atualiza a lista cliente
        atualizaClientes(this.jTFNick.getText());
        //escreve uma msg no textAreaChat que um determinado usuario se conectou
        enviaMsg(this.jTFNick.getText() + " entrou.");
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jBConectarActionPerformed

    private void jBEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBEnviarActionPerformed
        enviaMsg(this.jTFNick.getText() + " disse: " + this.jTFMensagem.getText());

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jBEnviarActionPerformed
    private void jEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) throws IOException {

    }

    private void jTFMensagemKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            //para enviar msg apenas com Enter
            enviaMsg(this.jTFNick.getText() + " disse: " + this.jTFMensagem.getText());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmissorReceptor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmissorReceptor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmissorReceptor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EmissorReceptor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new EmissorReceptor().setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jBConectar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBEnviar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTAChat;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTAClientes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTFIp;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTFMensagem;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTFNick;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: Cadê o erro? Adicione a pilha na pergunta.

Comment: //da erro nesse construtor, a causa eh os argumentos que se pede
    public EmissorReceptor(String ip, int Porta) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.porta = Porta;
    }
    private EmissorReceptor() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

Comment: Seu codigo nao é executavel. O método `recebeMsg` tem erro de passagem de parametro, corrige ai e edite a pergunta.

Comment: sim eu sei que não e executável, mas o que quero ajuda e na construtor do método EmissorReceptor que recebe o ip e porta

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não é reproduzível, mas posso sugerir que a causa do erro seja aqui:

```
private EmissorReceptor() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Você criou um construtor sem parâmetros(ou a sua IDE gerou ele, provavelmente), lançando exceção por não ter sido implementado. Creio que esteja utilizando Netbeans, que costuma criar métodos no automático dessa forma.

No main você não passa parâmetro nenhum pro construtor, então a classe invocará esse e lançará a exceçao.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new EmissorReceptor().setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Ou você passa os parâmetros pedidos no outro construtor da classe `EmissorReceptor` corretamente no main e remove esse construtor padrão ai, ou tire esse lançamento de exceção e implemente um construtor vazio.